# Is it bad to have a huge amount of ACLs on GCP?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm creating several mirror buckets from S3 to GCS. On S3, I have different permissions on different directories on the same bucket. To replicate this behavior on GCP, I have two options:

1. create one ACL for each file where I want to change permission.
2. create more buckets where S3's bucket `some-name` are represented on GCP by `some-name-private` and `some-name-public` and so on.

My doubt is about the drawbacks of each option. Option 2 clearly makes it harder to read from GCP, since I have to decide in which bucket is my file. Option 1 makes me call GCS twice: one to upload the file, other to set ACL. Does option 1 have any drawback considering price and/or delays during reads?

Comment: ACLs are legacy in both S3 and GCS. Are you unable to achieve the fine-grained control you need purely with bucket policies and IAM policies?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm not. I want to have a `allUsers` accessible dir and an `allAuthenticatedUsers` dir on the same bucket on GCS. But I got this msg setting fine-grained permissions: `Conditions are not allowed on public principals allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation for ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists),

> The maximum number of ACL entries you can create for a bucket or object is 100. When the entry scope is a group or domain, it counts as one ACL entry regardless of how many users are in the group or domain.

When it comes to performance, it would depend on the size of the object. The maximum size would be 5 TiB across the cloud storage. You can view the documentation on [object quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects).

When it comes to pricing, you can check this link for [GCP Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). You can configure your setup and the number of instances that you want to process.

You can also check ACL best practices [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#security) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#bestpractices)